# update settings after dropdown menu filter handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

i got a simple question, in Handsontable i want to update settings after i apply filter, for example by value in dropdown menu, to be certain to update merged cells actually.

i have a handsontable with `filters: true` and `dropdownMenu: true` but i have also `mergeCells: mergedCells` and if im trying to apply filter, the mergedcells brakes, because it needs to be updated.

so i decided to use `afterRender: function` when i apply filters from dropdown menu, i call function that recreate the array of merged cells and trying to updateSettings from afterRender function but the render starts looping infinitely while rerender. Also tried to use addHook with after render but it is actually the same thing. Any ideas how i can achieve mergecells update after filter is applied from dropdown menu?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to it, instead of using `afterRender` i should use `afterFilter` function